# Visual Studio 2015 Freezes when adding any text to a textbox only on IE

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio

Using the following line

document.getElementById("Txt_LawsByClassList").value = "xyz";

VS hangs for ever on IE and works fine on google chrome

Comment: What do you mean by "VS hangs forever on IE" - are you describing using VS's integration with IE's JavaScript debugger? Are you also using IE's F12 dev-tools?

Comment: Running the project during development if I chose Google Chrome it works fine but using IE it hangs (play icon gives options IE Google Chrome firefox ....)

Comment: Is it only on the one page that it fails? If you make a new minimal page to try to reproduce the problem, does it hang on that too? If you run it outside of VS, does IE hang?

Comment: You are right, it is working fine outside VS, do you suggest any action that should be taken?

Comment: @saljas Yes, don't test it with IE in VS :) Neither IE nor VS2015 will be updated (assuming you're using the latest versions of each), so finding what the bug is would be down to you and might not be of any use anyway. It seems likely that that combination works on other computers - perhaps the antivirus software is getting in the way.

Comment: Thank you for the help and thanks to every one who tried to help in this question